# Plot an image/matrix in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, wxwidgets

What's the simplest way to plot an image or matrix in wxWidgets? I've used wxMathPlot for simple y-vs-x scatter or line plots, but what if my data is an image?

I've seen libraries that integrate OpenGL with wxWidgets such as https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxGLCanvas - are there any alternatives?

Comment: How about [wxImagePanel](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/An_image_panel)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wxImage and draw raw rgb bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910748/wximage-and-draw-raw-rgb-bytes)